# Where clause in power query editor

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need to add this where clause in power query editor?

```
WHERE (ost_ticket.closed >= DATE_ADD((CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL - 31 DAY)
AND ost_ticket.created <= (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND ost_ticket.closed <= (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND ost_ticket.status_id <> 1)
OR (ost_ticket.status_id = 1)
```

I did try creating a custom column with:

```
if (
    ([Date Closed] >= DateTime.LocalNow() - #duration(31, 0, 0, 0) and [Date Created] <= DateTime.LocalNow() and [Date Closed] <= DateTime.LocalNow() and [status_id] <> 1)
    or [status_id] = 1
) then 1 else 0
```

but then it only shows 1 and not 0

Comment: Provide some sample data that is NOT supposed to return a 1. Maybe it is working fine, we can't tell   Also is the desire( A and B and C and D ) or (E)  or ( A and B and C) and (D or E)